# How can I have database connectivity for HTML5 for mobile applications to store data on a web server?

Tags: android, html, webserver, database-connectivity

How can I have database connectivity for HTML5 for mobile applications to store data on a web server?

For now, I am trying for an [Android](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_%28operating_system%29) device, but I will also be using it for [iPhone](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPhone). I am using the [Eclipse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eclipse_%28software%29) editor.

Comment: do you want to store the data on a mysql database?

Answer (score 0):

The most typical way to do this is to build a web service that acts as a frontend for the data you want to store.

You will have to create website which can accept and process some data, potentially persisting, modifying or retrieving from a database, and access this website from the app's code.

Providing direct access to a database to arbitrary users would be very unwise.